# C++ Force non constexpr context

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, constexpr

I have functions that are declared withe the `constexpr` specifier and i have already tested that they are be evaluated at compile time in unit tests.

Now I want to use sanitizers with my unit test to find even more problems. But because so much of my functions are specified with `constexpr` I'm not sure how to do it because if a function is evaluated at compile time the sanitizers are useless or not?

Is there some way to force a `constexpr` function to be not evaluated a compile time.
Or do you have some other recommendations.

Comment: Both GCC, Clang, and MSVC don't seem to evaluate constexpr functions at compile-time in unoptimized builds (as well as debug builds), unless they are used in a context where a compile-time constant is required.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way to force a constexpr function to be not evaluated a compile time [?]

If you can modify the `constexpr` function, adding an unused parameter, you can force run-time evaluation passing a run-time value.

I mean... suppose you have the following `constexpr` function

```
constexpr int getVal ()
 { return 0; }
```

you can use it as follows

```
constexpr auto a = getVal();

auto b = getVal();
```

and (ignoring the "as is" rule) you're sure that `getVal()` is computed compile-time initializing `a` but you don't know if it's computed compile-time or run-time initializing `b`.

But if you modify the function as follows

```
constexpr int getVal (int)
 { return 0; }
```

you can write

```
   int c = 1;

   constexpr auto a = getVal(0);

   auto b = getVal(c);
```

now you can be confident that `getVal()` is computed compile-time initializing `a` (because `a` is `constexpr` and `0` is a literal) and that is computed run-time initializing `b` (because `c` can't be used in a `constexpr` expression).

You can also verify that writing

```
int c = 1;

constexpr auto a = getVal(c);
```

you get a compilation error because `a` must be initialized compile-time but `getVal(c)` can't be computed compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to force a constexpr function to be not evaluated a compile time.

`constexpr` tells the compiler that the function and anything it calls should be safe to evaluate. One thing you can't do, for instance is `new` or `delete`. The restrictions on `constexpr` mean a whole lot of the pitfalls that sanitizers were built to catch are avoided implicitly.

> Or do you have some other recommendations.

Sanitizers remain useful. For example you could have invoked undefined behaviour. Just because a lot of your code is `constexpr` does not mean the bits that are not are implicitly also safe.